# Передача цифр посредством ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

столкнулся с проблемой передачи values с селектора. дело в том, что при использовании ajax неправильно передает значения, или я не знаю, как их правильно передавать. дело в том, что при занесении этих цифр в базу данных они не сохраняются, а если переносить их как строку text, то сохраняются там как Array. можете подсказать, как решить такую проблему? вот код -

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var search = $("#searchbutt");
        search.click(function() {
            var janrs = $("#janrs").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/obrabotchik.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: ({
                    janrs: janrs
                })
            });
        });
    });
```

php обработчик-

```
mysqli_query($CONNECTDB, "INSERT INTO `test` (`test`) VALUES ($_POST[janrs])");
```

и селектор -

```
<select name="selected_category[]" id="janrs" class="chosen-select" multiple data-placeholder="По каким жанрам искать">
                                <option                             value="72">
                    Альтернативная история
                </option>
                                <option                             value="43">
                    Альтернативная реальность
                </option>
                                <option                             value="44">
                    Ангелы
                </option>
                                <option                             value="26">
                    Андроиды
                </option>
                                <option                             value="73">
                    Антивойна
                </option>
                                <option                             value="74">
                    Антиутопия
                </option>
                                <option                             value="92">
                    Баскетбол
                </option>
                                <option                             value="107">
                    Безумие
                </option>
                                <option                             value="2">
                    Бисёнэн
                </option>
                                <option                             value="64">
                    Боевые искусства
                </option>
                                <option                             value="45">
                    Божества
                </option>
                                <option                             value="46">
                    Вампиры
                </option>
                                <option                             value="47">
                    Ведьмы
                </option>
                                <option                             value="13">
                    Вестерн
                </option>
                                <option                             value="61">
                    Виртуальная реальность
                </option>
                                <option                             value="76">
                    Военная тематика
                </option>
                                <option                             value="75">
                    Война
                </option>
                                <option                             value="19">
                    Воры
                </option>
                                <option                             value="77">
                    Гарем
                </option>
                                <option                             value="96">
                    Гарем (для девочек)
                </option>
                                <option                             value="102">
                    Гендерная интрига
                </option>
                                <option                             value="48">
                    Демоны
                </option>
                                <option                             value="14">
                    Детектив
                </option>
                                <option                             value="4">
                    Дзёсэй
                </option>
                                <option                             value="49">
                    Драконы
                </option>
                                <option                             value="15">
                    Драма
                </option>
                                <option                             value="50">
                    Зомби
                </option>
                                <option                             value="104">
                    Игры
                </option>
                                <option                             value="38">
                    Инопланетные расы
                </option>
                                <option                             value="29">
                    Искусственный интеллект
                </option>
                                <option                             value="78">
                    Искусство
                </option>
                                <option                             value="80">
                    Исторический
                </option>
                                <option                             value="105">
                    Исэкай
                </option>
                                <option                             value="81">
                    Киберпанк
                </option>
                                <option                             value="39">
                    Киборги
                </option>
                                <option                             value="16">
                    Комедия
                </option>
                                <option                             value="40">
                    Космос
                </option>
                                <option                             value="82">
                    Кулинария
                </option>
                                <option                             value="83">
                    Лоликон
                </option>
                                <option                             value="34">
                    Любовный треугольник
                </option>
                                <option                             value="51">
                    Магия
                </option>
                                <option                             value="99">
                    Манга
                </option>
                                <option                             value="20">
                    Мафия/Якудза
                </option>
                                <option                             value="5">
                    Махо-сёдзё
                </option>
                                <option                             value="106">
                    Машины
                </option>
                                <option                             value="25">
                    Меха
                </option>
                                <option                             value="31">
                    Мистика
                </option>
                                <option                             value="79">
                    Музыка
                </option>
                                <option                             value="101">
                    Не японское
                </option>
                                <option                             value="85">
                    Нелинейный сюжет
                </option>
                                <option                             value="65">
                    Ниндзя
                </option>
                                <option                             value="21">
                    Охотники за головами
                </option>
                                <option                             value="62">
                    Параллельные миры
                </option>
                                <option                             value="17">
                    Пародия
                </option>
                                <option                             value="66">
                    Перестрелки
                </option>
                                <option                             value="27">
                    Пилотируемые роботы
                </option>
                                <option                             value="22">
                    Пираты
                </option>
                                <option                             value="86">
                    Повседневность
                </option>
                                <option                             value="87">
                    Политика
                </option>
                                <option                             value="88">
                    Полицейские
                </option>
                                <option                             value="97">
                    Полулюди
                </option>
                                <option                             value="89">
                    Постапокалиптика
                </option>
                                <option                             value="18">
                    Преступность
                </option>
                                <option                             value="52">
                    Призраки
                </option>
                                <option                             value="32">
                    Приключения
                </option>
                                <option                             value="67">
                    Прокси бои
                </option>
                                <option                             value="98">
                    Психология
                </option>
                                <option                             value="41">
                    Путешествия во времени
                </option>
                                <option                             value="33">
                    Романтика
                </option>
                                <option                             value="53">
                    Русалки
                </option>
                                <option                             value="90">
                    Русские в аниме
                </option>
                                <option                             value="68">
                    Самураи
                </option>
                                <option                             value="103">
                    Сверхъестественное
                </option>
                                <option                             value="6">
                    Сёдзё
                </option>
                                <option                             value="7">
                    Сёдзё-ай
                </option>
                                <option                             value="8">
                    Сёнэн
                </option>
                                <option                             value="9">
                    Сёнэн-ай
                </option>
                                <option                             value="28">
                    Силовые костюмы
                </option>
                                <option                             value="54">
                    Современное фэнтези
                </option>
                                <option                             value="91">
                    Спорт
                </option>
                                <option                             value="69">
                    Сражения на мечах
                </option>
                                <option                             value="93">
                    Стимпанк
                </option>
                                <option                             value="55">
                    Суккубы
                </option>
                                <option                             value="70">
                    Суперспособности
                </option>
                                <option                             value="10">
                    Сэйнэн
                </option>
                                <option                             value="94">
                    Тайный заговор
                </option>
                                <option                             value="56">
                    Темное фэнтези
                </option>
                                <option                             value="57">
                    Темные эльфы
                </option>
                                <option                             value="23">
                    Террористы
                </option>
                                <option                             value="30">
                    Трансформеры
                </option>
                                <option                             value="35">
                    Триллер
                </option>
                                <option                             value="24">
                    Убийцы
                </option>
                                <option                             value="36">
                    Ужасы
                </option>
                                <option                             value="37">
                    Фантастика
                </option>
                                <option                             value="58">
                    Феи
                </option>
                                <option                             value="42">
                    Фэнтези
                </option>
                                <option                             value="95">
                    Школьная жизнь
                </option>
                                <option                             value="63">
                    Экшен
                </option>
                                <option                             value="60">
                    Эльфы
                </option>
                                <option                             value="100">
                    Эротика
                </option>
                                <option                             value="11">
                    Этти
                </option>
                        </select>
                </div>
```

Comment: Тебе не кажется что достаточно опубликовать 3-5 опций селектора, а не всю сотню? Что касается вопроса - итерируйся по `$_POST[janrs]` и вставляй каждый элемент.

Comment: Лучше конечно структуру таблицы показать, чтобы логика была ясна.

Comment: Вау, какая табуляция (ужос)

Answer (score 0):

Неправильный `insert` у вас, в запрос уходит массив.

1. Либо `insert` делать через цикл и писать каждое значение массива в отдельную строку.
2. Если вы поле в базе делаете типа `text` и сохранятся `Array`, ну тогда на что вы рассчитываете передавая в текстовое поле массив?
3. `json_encode($_POST['janrs']);` при поле типа `text` в базе, когда будете доставать, `json_decode($row['janr']);`.

Ну и такой запрос `"INSERT INTO test (test) VALUES ($_POST[janrs])"` как минимум должен вызвать проблему, что количество значений не совпадает с количеством столбцов в таблице (условно таблица из одного столбца `int janr`, а вы отдаете туда при лучших условиях, но не в этом случае `45, 44, 72` <- так не делается).